# how to group kendo ui editor tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo inline editor.I am displaying all tools except **"view HTML"**I am trying to group the tools like,"Bold","Italic","underline","strike through" in one group and all the text-alignments in one group ,....and it is like a menu,if we hover the parent icon ,remaining icons display like sub items in menu.
I have defines editor like

```
$("#topEditor").kendoEditor({
        tools: [
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "underline",
                "strikethrough",
                "justifyLeft",
                "justifyCenter",
                "justifyRight",
                "justifyFull",
                "insertUnorderedList",
                "insertOrderedList",
                "indent",
                "outdent",
                "createLink",
                "unlink",
                "insertImage",
                "subscript",
                "superscript",
                "createTable",
                "addRowAbove",
                "addRowBelow",
                "addColumnLeft",
                "addColumnRight",
                "deleteRow",
                "deleteColumn",
                "formatting",
                "fontName",
                "fontSize",
                "foreColor",
                "backColor"
                        ]
                    });
             });
```

can any one tell me how can we achieve this?

Comment: You can achieve this thing by using, custom template. Please check the below demo. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/editor/custom-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by the Kendo UI editor.